# Creating table in Firebird script causes "unsuccessful metadata update" with deadlock

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I have the following script that I run using "isql -i scriptfile.sql":

```
CONNECT C:\Databasefile.fdb USER user PASSWORD password;

SET TERM !! ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM rdb$relations WHERE rdb$relation_name = 'MYTABLE')) THEN
EXECUTE STATEMENT 'DROP TABLE MYTABLE;';
END!!
SET TERM ; !!

CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
(
  MYCOLUMN      VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
);
```

The very first time I run this (when the table does not already exist) the table is created as expected.
If I run the script again I get the following error:

```
Statement failed, SQLCODE = -607
unsuccessful metadata update
-STORE RDB$RELATIONS failed
-deadlock
After line 8 in file d:\myscript.sql
```

When the script exits, MYTABLE has been deleted and can no longer be found in the database.
If I run the script a third time the table is once again created and no errors are thrown.

Why can't the script both delete and then recreate a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDL from PSQL is not allowed, using `EXECUTE STATEMENT` it is not directly forbidden, and usually possible, but still not wise exactly because of these kinds of problems. I am not exactly sure about the reasons, but part of it have to do with how DDL changes are applied in Firebird; the use of execute statement adds additional locks iirc which conflict with a subsequent DDL for the same table name.

Instead of dropping and creating this way, you should use the DDL statement [`RECREATE TABLE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-recreate) instead.

Note that the word *deadlock* in this error is actually a bit of a misnomer (there is no real deadlock).

Comment: `RECREATE` seems to have done the trick. The `ALTER TABLE` I have just after `RECREATE` to add some foreign key constraints also seems to work. Thanks :)

Comment: @GTHvidsten You're welcome. Note that you don't actually need alter table to add constraints: you can do that inside a (re)create table.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it's so easy to just copy the DDL from Database Workbench ;)