# Dropping table fails with 'unsuccessful metadata update' when using embedded Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My code does the following:

1. Set up a design time target `TFDConnection`
2. Create a run time source `TFDConnection`
3. Drop all indices and tables in target
4. Recreate those
5. Copy all data from source to target
6. Drop one of those tables (and indices), named `TT_SYS_WEEKS`
7. Recreate it and fill it

The TFDConnections can be embedded Firebird or not. This works fine in all combinations *except* when both are embedded.

In step 6, after executing

```
DROP INDEX <OWNER>TT_I1_SYS_WEEKS
ALTER TABLE <OWNER>TT_SYS_WEEKS DROP CONSTRAINT TT_I0_SYS_WEEKS
```

the statement

```
DROP TABLE TT_SYS_WEEKS
```

fails with `[FireDAC][FB][Phys]unsuccesful metadata update Table TT_SYS_WEEKS already exists`.

The exact same operations of dropping and creating tables/indices were already performed in steps 3,4,5. `TT_SYS_WEEKS` is not the last table that was copied.

The design time target connection and its `TFDPhysFBDriverLink` are set up as follows:

```
AConnection.TxOptions.AutoCommit := true;
AFDPhysDriverLink.DriverID := 'FBEmbeddedBase';  // JD 28-3-2018
AFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib := 'fbembed.dll';  // 32-bits only
AConnection.Params.DriverID := 'FBEmbeddedBase'; // AConnection
AConnection.Params.Database := 'full GDB file';
SetFireBirdMapRules(AConnection); // Some mapping rules
AConnection.UpdateOptions.LockWait := False;
AConnection.UpdateOptions.LockMode := lmNone;
```

The runtime source connection and `TFDPhysFBDriverLink` are set up as follows:

```
// Create 'own' TFDPhysFBDriverLink for embedded connection
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691699/setting-up-a-second-tfdphysfbdriverlink-possible-and-necessary
lDriverLink := TFDPhysFBDriverLink.Create(Application);
lDriverLink.DriverID := 'FBEmbedded';
lDriverLink.VendorLib := 'fbembed.dll';  // 32-bits embedded
LRestoreDB := TFDConnection.Create(Application);
LRestoreDB.UpdateOptions.RequestLive     := false; 
LRestoreDB.ResourceOptions.AutoReconnect := true;
LRestoreDB.Params.DriverID := lDriverLink.DriverID; 
with LRestoreDB do
begin
   Params.Database := AFBFileName;
   Params.UserName := '***';
   Params.Password := '***';
   LoginPrompt := False;
   // ResourceOptions.KeepConnection is default true
   FetchOptions.Mode := fmAll;
end;
SetFireBirdMapRules(LRestoreDB); // Some mapping rules
```

**What can be going on**?
Anything else I can investigate?

Other background info:

- Data was copied to the target database with parameterized `INSERT` queries, for many tables. A transaction with explicit commit was around each table transfer.
- In the table copy operations `TxOptions.AutoCommit` is true for the target database
- Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 Win32 app, Firebird 2.5.3.25778 Win32
- [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442737/creating-table-in-firebird-script-causes-unsuccessful-metadata-update-with-dea) had an issue with CREATE following DROP. In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442970/512728), [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) writes *the use of execute statement adds additional locks iirc which conflict with a subsequent DDL for the same table name*. That is PSQL under Firebird 2.1, does not mention embedded, and I don't have the *deadlock* error.

Comment: Wrap every DDL (schema changing) operation into an explicit commit also.  Your "DROP TABLE TT_SYS_WEEKS" statement seems to be deleting the table, but the error clearly says you tried to CREATE the table or view - "Table TT_SYS_WEEKS already exists.".

Comment: Well, I'm not creating it, that's for sure. I'll try your suggestion, though I'm not happy with it. My steps 3 and 4 will then be littered with explicit transactions too.

Comment: You do not issue the creating statement at this moment, but you seem to trigger the commit, whish is creating - and failing. 
Committing after dropping is quite recommended, against "object in use" error. Maybe FireDAC has auto-commit-DDL option, maybe it works reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a commit after step 4, 5 and 6 (and - of course - 7). Some of the DDL in Firebird is only really executed on commit, so if you run everything in one transaction, you won't have actually dropped and recreated the indexes yet in steps 3 and 4, the table drop in step 6 might be blocked by the earlier DML in step 5, and the table drop in step 6 will not have been executed yet when you try to recreate it in step 7.

Comment: Would this be the case for Interbase as well? And do MSSQL, MySQL and Oracle (the other DB types that we handle) not have this issue?

Comment: OK, this works. Luckily all my SQL goes through two statements so I can easily check there if I need to do transactions (for now: if FireBird and DDL). One caveat though: The default UpdateOptions.LockWait=false has to be set TRUE, otherwise I get *Lock conflict on no wait transaction* errors

Comment: There was a discussion about waiting transactions and SP dropping, it was explained from implementation point of view.

Comment: @JanDoggen Can't recall specifics for those other systems, but some database systems will implicitly commit after a DDL statement, and others will simply disallow usage DML and DDL usage of the same objects in a single transaction, etc. Regarding the behavior with wait vs no wait, that is an oddity that I think is a bug, but IIRC the Firebird core developers disagree on that.

Comment: @JanDoggen You might also want to try if upgrading to Firebird 2.5.8 helps, IIRC there were some changes in this area. Right now I don't have time to double-check the release notes between 2.5.3 and 2.5.8.

Comment: That is why Firebird/Interbase specific library UIB in its `TUIBScript` component has an `AutoDDL` property :-D